# Vectorization with SpaCy tools in Python

Tags: python, nlp, vectorization, spacy

Please be patient I am new to Python.

- I download more than 3 millions of Tweet every day.
- I need to process it daily.
- I use mainly Spacy library to perform the analysis
- I write my process and it work.
- To get it more fast I used vectorization everywhere

My problem is with "lemmatization" where, I think, I am not able to vectorize pand to gain in speed.

This is my code NOT vectorized:

```
def lem2(stringa):
    return " ".join([token.lemma_ for token in nlp(stringa) ])

try:
    df[text_lem] = df[text_clean].apply(lambda x: lem(x) )
except Exception as ee:
    printg("ERROR: %s" % str(ee))
```

It works but it's slow. "**nlp**", "**lemma_**" and "**lem**" are from SpaCy.

This is my code vectorized:

```
def lem3(numpy_array: np.array) -> np.array:
    return " ".join([token.lemma_ for token in nlp(numpy_array) ])

aaa = df2['text_clean'].to_numpy()
applyall = np.vectorize( lem3 )
df2['text_lem'] = applyall( aaa )
```

But I have not a gain in performance.

Why? I read a lot about vectorization but I think I am missing something.

It must be vectorized in another way?

Anyone can suggest me a solution?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need parsing and processing each string individually, and it depends on the Spacy library, which is not designed to be vectorized.

You need to speed up lemmatization.

As an example:

```
import pandas as pd
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

def lem(doc):
    return " ".join([token.lemma_ for token in doc])

docs = list(nlp.pipe(df['text_clean'], batch_size=1000))
df['text_lem'] = [lem(doc) for doc in docs]
```